# Create new openshift application

Tags: eclipse, ssh, jboss, openshift

When I try to create a new openshift application in Eclipse, they show me this error:

```
The authenticity of host 'droptest-daasenv.rhcloud.com' can't be established . RSA key fingerprint is cf:ee:....:a7.
```

When I click next, they show this msg:

```
Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
 Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.
ssh://56a4d5fb7628e14ac3000081@droptest-daasenv.rhcloud.com/~/git/droptest.git/: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
```

Can you guys tell me what should I do?

Comment: Hi. Question not specific enough. Sounds like you haven't configured your SSH keys, but there are a few steps there. Start with [Using OpenShift in Eclipse](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-eclipse.html) and repost if you have problem with specific step.

Comment: I did the same steps again , when i click finish ; they show me the second message !! ( my ssh preferences contains the name of my private key )

Comment: So, what happens when you run `rhc setup`?

Comment: ohh yea ! I forgot configure this .. I finally create the app but still one thing : when I modify index.html and do "Commit" .. I can t see the modification !!!

Comment: Push it, or if you have openshift in the server's list, use publish.

Comment: yea it works !! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already have a RH cloud account.

In this case you just need to configure yout SSH keys for OpenShift online:

http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/openshift_configssh.html

A second option is: take a look at this page, where I put a 4-minutes (mute) video to show how to use JBossTools to connect to OpenShift Online:
http://www.asegno.com/jboss-dev/

Comment: yea right ! I did the same thing .. but you should mention the command 'rhc setup' to configure the ssh key